# Can I populate an XSLT variable with a dropdown menu?

Tags: xml, xslt

Please don't attack me for asking a noob question.
Anyhow here is what I am doing- I am working on an XSLT file that works with an XML file called software. i'm not going to write the whole thing just a little sample. there are more applications then just the one.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="form.xslt"?>
<software
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="form.xstl"

>
  <aplication>
    <tittle>Libre Office</tittle>
    <vendor>Libreoffice.org</vendor>
    <category>office suite</category>
    <platform>
      <software>Windows</software>
      <versions>XP sp 2</versions>
      <hardware cpu="pentium" ram="256mb"></hardware>
       </platform>
    <price>0</price>
```

In the style sheet there is a dropdown menu populated by the above HTML

```
<select name="softwareCategory" id="softwareCategory">
    <xsl:for-each select="//category[not(.=preceding::*)]"> 
    <option  value="{category}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>          
    </option> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
</select>
```

Anyhow bellow this I am working on a table- I am looking for the code that would populate an XSL variable called selectedCategory and populate it with the value selected in the menu.
If this can not be done in XSTL I plan to use jquery
Thank you for your time.
I am changing things to up date with the follwoing jquery which is not working

```
$('softwareCategory').change(function() {

var selectedCategory =$('softwareCategory').find('option:selected').text();

$.get("students.xml",{},function(xml){

        // Build an HTML string
        myHTMLOutput = '';
        myHTMLOutput += '<table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        myHTMLOutput += '<th>Name</th><th>title</th></th>';

        // Run the function for each aplication tag in the XML file
        $('apliation',xml).each(function(i) {
            title = $(this).find("title").text();


            // Build row HTML data and store in string
            mydata = buildSoftware(title);
            myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;
        });
        myHTMLOutput += '</table>'+selectedCategory;

        // Update the DIV called aprovedSoftwareTable with the HTML string
        $("aprovedSoftwareTable").append(myHTMLOutput);
    });

function BuildSoftware () {
output = '';
output += '<tr>';
output += '<td>';
output +=   '<input type="checkbox" name="value="'+title+'"" value="'+title+'">';
output += '</td>';
output += '<td>';
output += title;
output += '<td>';
output += '</tr>';

return output;
}
});
});
```

Comment: XSLT is not interactive. The *value* of your `option` doesn't live inside a file (not even in HTML). But -- you can assign external variables through the command line for the XSLT processor, with Saxon for example: http://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200501/msg00226.html

Comment: Command line won't work- I'll use jquery then. Now to figure out how to fix this error "Unsafe attempt to load URL form.xsl from frame with URL software.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The main thing missing is the purpose. "*The code that would populate a variable*" does not tell us anything about that. XSLT is a tool to transform the given XML into another document. It seem that in your case, the target document needs to be HTML.  If so, show us exactly what the resulting HTML code should be. -- P.S. It's OK to minimize the example - but it should still be a complete, well-formed XML document; your input is not.

Comment: the point to the variable is to populate a chart based on the variable. The initial plan was to populate a variable called category which would then grab the data and make a chart that is - title and OS. If I could not populate the variable using XSL then I would need to figure out how to do it with jquery

Comment: Are you running this in the browser? If so, the conventional architecture is that XSLT generates the HTML and then leaves the scene, long before the user has any chance to interact with the HTML page. But you could consider Saxon-CE, which allows you to handle user interaction events from within the XSLT code.

Comment: Yes I am running it in the browser- and as I figured that XSLT and XML was doing what you said- I decided perhaps I should use jquery as I could write a function called WriteTable- link it to an unchange that writes the table when ever  the dropdown is dropped down something like this
I am adding